# Leibniz approximation - Java

Tags: java, pi

So, I'm trying to write a program that will approximate PI. I think I have Leibniz's formula in correctly but my numbers are coming up wrong. Can anyone spot whats wrong in my code? Or if its just totally screwed up.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pi2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Number of sentances: ");
    double sent = input.nextDouble();
    double den = 1;
    double LeiPI;
    for(int i = 0;i <= sent;i++)
    {
      double firstden = (1/den);
      double firstVAR = 1 - firstden;
      double secvar = (Math.pow(-1, (sent + 1)) / ((2 * sent) - 1));
      double thirdvar = firstVAR + secvar;
      LeiPI = 4 * thirdvar;
      for(int j = 0;j < i;j++)
      {
        if(i < j)
          den++;
        den++;
      }
      if(i == sent)
        System.out.println(LeiPI);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) Please indent your code so that it is readable. 2) What does it do instead of what you expect?

Comment: When I enter, say 100, my answer should be 3.131593 but I am getting 3.979091

Comment: `if (i < j) den++; den++;` is highly dubious. That is semantically identical to `den++`, given the guard on the containing for loop, so that for loop can be removed and replaced with `den += i`. I'm guessing that's not what you intend.

Comment: I can't see why you'd do `1 - anything` to implement Leibniz's formula.

Comment: π = 4 (1-1/3 + 1/5 + ... + ((-1)^i+1)/2 - 1) is the formula we were given to use where the "..." is the number input by the user.

Comment: that's not the right general formula. Try it with `i = 0,1,2` etc, it doesn't yield the `1, -1/3, 1/5` etc terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it's totally screwed up (your words :o).

Going through your code line-by-line:

```
double den = 1;
double LeiPI;
```

You should be adding to `LeiPI` each time round the for loop. If you aren't doing this, all of your iteration state is in `den`. You *can't be* doing this, because you'd have to have initialized `LeiPI` to do so, owing to [definite assignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html).

```
for(int i = 0;i <= sent;i++)
```

You're actually iterating `(sent + 1)` times.

```
{
  double firstden = (1/den);
  double firstVAR = 1 - firstden;
```

Not clear what you're doing here. There is no `1 - anything` in a single term in [Leibniz's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) (obviously there is `1 - 1/3`): everything is just `+/- 1 / denominator`:

```
1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 - ... = pi/4
```

Anyway:

```
  double secvar = (Math.pow(-1, (sent + 1)) / ((2 * sent) - 1));
```

You've got the right idea here with the `-1` and the `/ ((2 * sent) - 1)`, but the numerator should be 1.

```
  double thirdvar = firstVAR + secvar;
  LeiPI = 4 * thirdvar;
  for(int j = 0;j < i;j++)
  {
    if(i < j)
      den++;
    den++;
  }
```

As I noted above, you are storing all of your iteration state in `den`, so all you're actually doing here is increasing `den` by `i` - so `den` is just increasing quadratically according to the triangle numbers.

```
  if(i == sent)
    System.out.println(LeiPI);
```

You should print `LeiPI` outside your loop, having initalized the variable previously.

```
}
```

I'd suggest that you forget about all of these extra variables: they just clutter it up and make it harder to read. Just implement the term as you see it in the formula.

The following gives the answer you state for `sent == 100`:

```
double LeiPI = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sent; i++) {
  LeiPI += 4.0 * Math.pow(-1, i) / (2.0 * i + 1);
}
System.out.println(LeiPI);
```